# ggplot theme_bw() does not work with read data, but same exact code works fine with mtcars data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data that looks like the following, about 2000 rows of it where sample_name is unique (it is actually a factor value, but I converted here to keep it hidden):

```
head(df)
  sample_name metric metric_name metric_mean metric_sd year_month
1           1      0   my_metric    154260.5  76782.54    2020-08
2           2 156845   my_metric    154260.5  76782.54    2020-08
3           3  78015   my_metric    154260.5  76782.54    2020-08
4           4  87620   my_metric    154260.5  76782.54    2020-08
5           5 102581   my_metric    154260.5  76782.54    2020-08
6           6 145976   my_metric    154260.5  76782.54    2020-08
```

I am using this RMD content to generate a PDF with the plot. The plot generated removes `theme_bw()` as shown in the output plot generated using the rmarkdown PDF conversion.

[image]

````
---
title: "Example"
author: John Doe
output: pdf_document
---

# Here is my plot

This is a plot of mpg vs. number of cylinders in a car.

```{r, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, eval = TRUE, message = FALSE, warn = FALSE}
  library(ggplot2)
  library(data.table)

  df <- fread('/tmp/gopala.csv', data.table = FALSE)
    metric_mean <- unique(df$metric_mean)
    metric_sd <- unique(df$metric_sd)
    metric_name <- unique(df$metric_name)
    year_month <- unique(df$year_month)

  ggplot(df, aes(x = sample_name, y = metric)) +
    geom_point(size = 0.5, color = '#1F77B4') +
    labs(
      title = paste0('CHART FOR PERIOD ', year_month),
      x = 'NAME', y = toupper(metric_name)
      ) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = metric_mean, color = 'red', size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = metric_mean + metric_sd, color = 'blue', size = 0.5
      ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = metric_mean - metric_sd,
      color = 'blue', linetype = 'dashed', size = 0.5
      ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = metric_mean + 2 * metric_sd, color = 'purple', size = 0.5
      ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = metric_mean - 2 * metric_sd,
      color = 'purple', linetype = 'dashed', size = 0.5
      ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = metric_mean + 3 * metric_sd, color = 'green', size = 0.5
      ) +
    geom_hline(
      yintercept = metric_mean - 3 * metric_sd,
      color = 'green', linetype = 'dashed', size = 0.5
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('Mean (', round(metric_mean, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean, color = 'red', fontface = 'bold'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('+1SD (', round(metric_mean + metric_sd, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean + metric_sd, color = 'blue'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('-1SD (', round(metric_mean - metric_sd, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean - metric_sd, color = 'blue'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('+2SD (', round(metric_mean + 2 * metric_sd, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean + 2 * metric_sd, color = 'purple'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('-2SD (', round(metric_mean - 2 * metric_sd, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean - 2 * metric_sd, color = 'purple'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('+3SD (', round(metric_mean + 3 * metric_sd, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean + 3 * metric_sd, color = 'green'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    geom_text(
      aes(
        label = paste0('-3SD (', round(metric_mean - 3 * metric_sd, 2), ')'),
        x = Inf, y = metric_mean - 3 * metric_sd, color = 'green'
        ),
      hjust = 1
      ) +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
      legend.position = 'none'
      )
```
````

Changing the first few lines to the following, makes everything work fine:

```
  metric_mean <- mean(mtcars$mpg)
  metric_sd <- sd(mtcars$mpg)

  ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
    geom_point(size = 0.5, color = '#1F77B4') +
    labs(
      title = 'WT vs. MPG', x = 'WT', y = 'MPG'
      ) +
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out the reason.

ADDITIONAL: If anyone knows how to nudge my 'text' labels up by a small amount (relative scale) without using absolute values, that would be of great help too.

[image]

Comment: When I run your code with the 6 rows of data, I get a white background (with axis lines) consistent with `theme_bw()`.

Comment: For offseting your labels, start with `vjust=0` (or even `=-0.1` (for each `geom_text`). You will run into issues with your top label, but you can use `coord_cartesian` or `ylim` to bump up a touch.

Comment: I'd think you could combine all of your `geom_text` into one call by setting up a single `data.frame` beforehand, such as `data.frame(x=Inf, y=metric_mean+..., label = ..., color = ...)`, and then `geom_text(data = newdf, aes(x, y, label = label, color = I(color)))`.

Comment: As I indicated, the data size is about 2000 rows, and I fear that has something to do with the `theme_bw()` disappearing? If so, how to fix it?

Comment: I understand that the 6 rows does not represent the 2000 rows. I just replicated your data from 6 rows to 6000 rows, and I get the same results. The number of rows should have no impact on the behavior of `theme_bw()`. Have you tried restarting R? I know it sounds draconian, but R is not immune from problems that a fresh restart fixes.